# spring mvc project with maven using STS

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating Spring MVC project with maven using STS. But in my `pom.xml` I have following error:

> Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:pom:1.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:pom:1.6 from/to central (http://  repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.6/plexus-interpolation-1.6.pom

Comment: I edited your question. Next time be careful to write your question with proper case and when possible with the right format.

Comment: Do you have maven installed? If so, just go to the directory that contains the pom.xml file and execute `mvn clean install -U` -U means force update which will download the file without checking your local repo cache.

Comment: I faced the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657335/spring-boot-batch-app-maven-error